# How to match two string arrays up with each other?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have two arrays:

**Array #1:**

```
let training = [
  "Z1,1545 John Doe,P1",
  "Z2,2415 Shane Yu,P2"
];
```

**Array #2:**

```
let skill = [
  "P1, Shooting",
  "P2, Passing",
];
```

Both arrays have to be concatenated together corresponding to their `P` number & remove the `P` from the training array.

**Desired Output:**

```
[ 
  'Z1,1545 John Doe, P1, Shooting',
  'Z2,2415 Shane Yu, P2, Passing'
]
```

Is there a way of doing this in ES6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build an ES6 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from your `skill` array, so that each `P<number>` points to a skill. Then you can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on your `training` array to get your desired result:

```js
const training = [ "Z1,1545 John Doe,P1", "Z2,2415 Shane Yu,P2" ];
const skill = [ "P1, Shooting", "P2, Passing", ];

const lookup = new Map(skill.map(item => [item.split(", ").shift(), item]));
const result = training.map(str => str.replace(/P\d+/, m => lookup.get(m)));
console.log(result);
```

You could also skip the creation of the Map, and do a linear search with [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`.startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) in the replace method. This is less efficient though if `skills` has many skills (ie: it's O(NK) vs the O(N+K) above):

```js
const training = [ "Z1,1545 John Doe,P1", "Z2,2415 Shane Yu,P2" ];
const skills = [ "P1, Shooting", "P2, Passing"];

const result = training.map(str => str.replace(/P\d+/, m => skills.find(
  skill => skill.startsWith(m)
)));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the skill array can be converted to a Map object:

```js
let skillMap = new Map(skill.map(e=>e.split(“,”)))

// split(“,”) convert "P1, Shooting" into [“P1”,” Shooting”]
// skill.map return a new array with the converted elementos
// The Map object is created which each pair as key and value
```

Then you can iterate the training array selecting from skillMap the description of each skill you can make it in a lot of way but my first take will be:

```js
let output = training.map(e=>e.split(“,”)).map(e=>[e[0],e[1],e[2]+skillMap.get(e[2])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach:

```js
let training = [
    "Z1,1545 John Doe,P1",
    "Z2,2415 Shane Yu,P2"
];

let skill = [
    "P1, Shooting",
    "P2, Passing",
];

let merged = training.map((prefix) => {
  const [, , pIndex] = prefix.split(',');
  const suffix = skill.find((skillStr) => skillStr.startsWith(pIndex));
  
  return `${prefix}${suffix.slice(2)}`;
});

console.log(merged)
```